# Problema con el manejo de listas en JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con el manejo de las listas en `Java`

No sé como añadir elementos a una lista determinada, por ejemplo:

```
{2,4,5,7,9}
```

De manera que me salgan los números intermedios en la misma lista, es decir, modificando la principal, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Este es el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lista lista = new Lista();
    lista.insertarOrden(2);
    lista.insertarOrden(4);
    lista.insertarOrden(5);
    lista.insertarOrden(7);
    lista.insertarOrden(9);
    System.out.println(lista);
}

public class Lista {  
    public class Nodo {
        int info;
        private Nodo sig;
        public Nodo (int info) {
           this.info = info;
           sig = null;
        }
}

private Nodo primero;
    public void fill () {
       Nodo aux = primero;
       while (aux != null) {

    }
}

public void insertarOrden (int valor) {
    if (primero == null) {
        primero = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
    }else {
        if (primero.info > valor) {
            Lista.Nodo aux = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
            aux.sig = primero;
            primero = aux;
        }else {
            Lista.Nodo aux = primero;
            while (aux.sig != null && aux.sig.info < valor) {
                aux = aux.sig;
            }

            Lista.Nodo nuevo = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
            nuevo.sig = aux.sig;
            aux.sig = nuevo;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Daniel , bienvenido a SOes , sería necesario que añadieras el código que tienes hasta ahora para poder dar un mejor enfoque al problema. Gracias.

Comment: Ya he añadido el código que tengo

Comment: **Qué error tienes en el código ?** , al insertar ya parece que realizas el ordenamiento de los elementos.

Comment: si pero me falta desarrollar el método "fill"  para que a la lista principal se le añadan los valores intermedios. Esa es la parte que no se desarrollar.

Comment: Por favor también muéstranos el código del método `toString` de tu clase `Lista`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución sería tener una variable que tenga el valor del último elemento, para luego con un `for` insertar los elementos restantes , adicional mente eh añadido un método  `imprimir` para la Lista enlazada.

```
 public void fill () {
    Nodo aux = primero;
    int  ultimo=0;/* Varible Ultimo Inicializada en 0*/
    while (aux != null) {
     /* Si el valor del Nodo es Mayor que ultimo */
        if(aux.info>ultimo){
           /* Iteramos desde ultimo +1 hasta el siguiente valor del Siguiente Nodo
            y ese valor de i , le añadimos a la Lista*/
            for (int i = ultimo+1; i < aux.info; i++) {
                insertarOrden(i);
            }
            ultimo=aux.info; /* Asignamos a Ultimo el valor de Nodo*/
        }
        aux = aux.sig;
    }
}

public void Imprimir(){
    Nodo aux = primero;
    while (aux != null) {
        System.out.println(aux.info);
        aux=aux.sig;
    }
}


/* Explicación por Iteración  lista = (2,4,5,7,9)`, ultimo =0
1 Iteración :
    Valor de Aux.info = 2 -> if(2>0)==  TRUE
    For : Desde i=(0+1) hasta Aux.info =2 {
       Insertamos(1);
    }
    ultimo = aux.info =2;
2 Iteración :
    Valor de Aux.info = 4 -> if(4>2)==  TRUE
    For : Desde i=(2+1) hasta Aux.info =4 {
       Insertamos(3);
    }
    ultimo = aux.info =4;
3 Iteración :
    Valor de Aux.info = 5 -> if(5>4)==  TRUE
    For : Desde i=(4+1) hasta Aux.info =5 {
       No se Inserta Nada
    }
    ultimo = aux.info =5;
4 Iteración :
    Valor de Aux.info = 7 -> if(7>5)==  TRUE
    For : Desde i=(5+1) hasta Aux.info =7 {
       Insertamos(6)
    }
    ultimo = aux.info =7;
5 Iteración :
    Valor de Aux.info = 9 -> if(9>7)==  TRUE
    For : Desde i=(7+1) hasta Aux.info =9 {
       Insertamos(8)
    }
    ultimo = aux.info =9;
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Deberías poner el código que tienes para ser mas precisos, pero te dejo un ejemplo:

Con la clase Collections y el método sort de la siguiente forma:

```
Collections.sort(listaNumeros);
```

Por lo que tu ejemplo completo quedaría:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ListarNumeros
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lista.add(8); 
    lista.add(6); 
    lista.add(3);

    Collections.sort(lista);

    for (Integer numero: lista) {
        System.out.println(numero);
    }   

  }
}
```

Resultado:

3
6
8

Comment: ya he puesto el código que tengo. Y... se podría hacer con nodos en vez de con arrayList?

Comment: No lo he intentado con nodos pero podría funcionar tal ves de la siguiente forma Collections.sort( lista,  comparator );

Comment: Es una clase particular, no se puede ordenar con `Collections#sort`